# kernel missing nf_tables_inet module in Solus

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, kernel, kernel-module

the title says it all. Solus Linux kernels are missing numerous kernel modules essential to successfully operating nftables! why is it even a pkg in the eopkg repos if they don't compile their kernels with:

- nf_tables_inet
- nf_tables_ipv6
- nf_tables_ipv4

those 3 modules dictate what families your chains belong to. you cant even enter a chain without them! if you do, you get the dreaded & equally vague "Error: Could not process rule: Operation not supported" result. arrgh! so frustrating! such a great distro in every other way thus far, superior in many ways even, but compiling kernels just for this? no thanks, the inferiority of iptables is less pain than that of compiling kernels. ugh I say!

does anyone know if I just failed to install some pkg or if there is any way to remedy this without compiling kernels from source? & yes, I've hunted online for weeks to no avail, which also shocks me b/c how can I be the 1st person to run face-first into this wall? (no pun intended!) Solus & nftables have been around for years, so I fear & hope (ironically both) that I am stupidly overlooking some basic, simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no prior Solus knowledge. Even finding Solus' repository wasn't that straightforward.

I downloaded a *linux-current* (5.6.13) kernel package [there](https://mirrors.rit.edu/solus/packages/shannon/l/linux-current/linux-current-5.6.13-153-1-x86_64.eopkg), and extracted it (the data part is basically a `.tar.xz` inside a `.zip`). The configuration inside `usr/lib/kernel/config-5.6.13-153.current` and among other things:

```
$ grep -E 'CONFIG_(NF_TABLES|NFT_)' usr/lib/kernel/config-5.6.13-153.current
CONFIG_NF_TABLES=m
# CONFIG_NF_TABLES_SET is not set
# CONFIG_NF_TABLES_INET is not set
# CONFIG_NF_TABLES_NETDEV is not set
# CONFIG_NFT_NUMGEN is not set
CONFIG_NFT_CT=m
# CONFIG_NFT_FLOW_OFFLOAD is not set
CONFIG_NFT_COUNTER=m
CONFIG_NFT_CONNLIMIT=m
CONFIG_NFT_LOG=m
CONFIG_NFT_LIMIT=m
CONFIG_NFT_MASQ=m
CONFIG_NFT_REDIR=m
CONFIG_NFT_TUNNEL=m
# CONFIG_NFT_OBJREF is not set
CONFIG_NFT_QUEUE=m
# CONFIG_NFT_QUOTA is not set
CONFIG_NFT_REJECT=m
CONFIG_NFT_COMPAT=m
CONFIG_NFT_HASH=m
# CONFIG_NFT_XFRM is not set
CONFIG_NFT_SOCKET=m
# CONFIG_NFT_OSF is not set
# CONFIG_NFT_TPROXY is not set
# CONFIG_NFT_SYNPROXY is not set
# CONFIG_NF_TABLES_IPV4 is not set
# CONFIG_NF_TABLES_ARP is not set
# CONFIG_NF_TABLES_IPV6 is not set
# CONFIG_NF_TABLES_BRIDGE is not set
```

The must-have things (eg: `CONFIG_NF_TABLES_IPV4` or `CONFIG_NF_TABLES_SET`) aren't here, while some optional things (eg: `CONFIG_MASQ` or `CONFIG_REJECT`) are present but quite useless without the higher protocol counterparts sometimes even provided by a separate module (eg: `CONFIG_NFT_REJECT_IPV4` not appearing at all). Likewise `CONFIG_NFT_COMPAT` is defined, but would still leave the *nftables API* variant of the *iptables* userland tool useless without the missing nftables options.

I can only think of a lack of interest about *nftables* from Solus to have not included this.

The only references I found about extra kernel packages are in https://getsol.us/articles/troubleshooting/boot-management/en/ but it's about external modules, not in-tree modules packaged separately. The unstable Solus repository appears to provide exactly the same linux kernel packages.

Now, checking the same with a [*linux-lts*](https://mirrors.rit.edu/solus/packages/shannon/l/linux-lts/linux-lts-4.9.223-158-1-x86_64.eopkg) package for Linux LTS 4.9 gets way better results (I kept it small):

```
$ grep -E 'CONFIG_(NF_TABLES|NFT_COMPAT)' usr/lib/kernel/config-4.9.223-158.lts
CONFIG_NF_TABLES=m
CONFIG_NF_TABLES_INET=m
CONFIG_NF_TABLES_NETDEV=m
CONFIG_NFT_COMPAT=m
CONFIG_NF_TABLES_IPV4=m
CONFIG_NF_TABLES_ARP=m
CONFIG_NF_TABLES_IPV6=m
CONFIG_NF_TABLES_BRIDGE=m
```

So you have a few choices:

- keep older LTS linux 4.9 kernel with adequate but a bit outdated *nftables* support (some features won't be available like notrack, fib lookup, tcp mss, connection tracking from bridge family, IPSec support, etc.),
- use current linux kernel without adequate *nftables* support: keep using legacy version of *iptables*,
- recompile current kernel

  There's no interest in trying to recompile all the missing modules (and other not appearing due to various other missing network options), it would probably be simpler to recompile everything. It looks the corresponding sources of the package I chose are at [https://dev.getsol.us/](https://dev.getsol.us/source/linux-current/browse/master/;linux-current-5.6.13-153) (and include very few patches):  but I don't know about Solus' build system to get a *eopkg* in the end rather than a direct installation from source. The current *nftables* configuration is [there](https://dev.getsol.us/source/linux-current/browse/master/files/config;linux-current-5.6.13-153$1135).
- petition with a bug report to have the missing options added and at least be on par with the LTS version.

Comment: you restated my understandings/fears quite well.  I auto-update the system incl the kernel so I've no interest in custom compiling anything.

I am astonished that I (a new Solus user) am the 1st to experience this (I still doubt I am).  I have found 0 posts from anyone asking or reporting this obvious oversight.  I'm still in disbelief: why would they include nftables in the kernel yet render it 100% useless?  esp after including it correctly in past kernel & including other entirely optional modules for it in this kernel?  do you have any insights into why anyone would do that?

Comment: though it did not solve my problem (no one except a Solus pkg maintainer could, based on the answer), the answer above is thorough, accurate, & very informative.  I wish it wasn't right!  but it is, for now ;)